# My osm2po java program compiles but gives a runtime error

Tags: java, osm2po

I need road distances and I'm trying to use osm2po to do this.

After downloading the OSM files and converting them to gph format, using the osm2po program, I start at the very beginning with the following very simple java program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import de.cm.osm2po.logging.Log;
import de.cm.osm2po.logging.Log2poConsoleWriter;
import de.cm.osm2po.model.LatLon;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.Graph;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.MultiTargetRouter;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.PoiRouter;

public class TestOSM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File graphFile = new File("C:/osm2po/osm2po-5.0.0/hh/hh_2po.gph");
        Graph graph = new Graph(graphFile);

        // Somewhere in Hamburg
        int sourceId = graph.findClosestVertexId(53.5f, 10.0f);
        int targetId = graph.findClosestVertexId(53.4f, 10.1f);
        graph.close();

    }
}
```

I get it to compile using:

```
javac -d . -classpath osm2po-core-5.0.0-signed.jar TestOSM.java
```

It compiles and creates the `TestOSM.class` file.

I then use the following to run the program:

```
java TestOSM
```

It gives a runtime error (I'll show the error message below)

I suspected the program does not read the `hh_2po.gph` file, so I used another java program to first use "normal" java file read to confirm successful file reading operation.

My java program to try to confirm successful file reading looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.io.Console;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import de.cm.osm2po.logging.Log;
import de.cm.osm2po.logging.Log2poConsoleWriter;
import de.cm.osm2po.model.LatLon;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.Graph;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.MultiTargetRouter;
import de.cm.osm2po.routing.PoiRouter;

public class TestOSM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Testing take1
        File graphFile = new File("C:/osm2po/osm2po-5.0.0/hh/hh_2po.gph");
        //File graphFile = new File(args[0]);  // tried this, and then supply file name when calling the program - does not work
        //File graphFile = new File("hh_2po.gph");  // tried this after copying hh_2po.gph in the same directory - does not work
        Graph graph = new Graph(graphFile);

        // Somewhere in Hamburg
        int sourceId = graph.findClosestVertexId(53.5f, 10.0f);
        int targetId = graph.findClosestVertexId(53.4f, 10.1f);
        graph.close();


/*
        // Testing take2
        // Part 1, to confirm that the program can read the hh_2po.gph file: 
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/osm2po/osm2po-5.0.0/hh/hh_2po.gph")));    
            String  thisLine = thisLine = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(thisLine);
            System.out.println("file read good");
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("could not read file");
        }
        System.out.println("enter to continue");
        Console console = System.console();
        String line = console.readLine();
        // end of test



        // Part 2, this time try to convert file to InputStream before converting to a Graph: 
        try{
            File initialFile = new File("C:/osm2po/osm2po-5.0.0/hh/hh_2po.gph");
            InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
            Graph graph = new Graph(targetStream);
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Heuston we have a problem");
        }
*/

    }
}
```

When I run it, again using java TestOSM, I get the following runtime error:

[image: screenshot of error message]

I use Windows10 and java jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: Please format your post properly, so code blocks are clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy need to specify the classpath. The error is saying that a class is not being found. Execute your file with the cp option:

```
java -cp osm2po-core-5.0.0-signed.jar TestOSM
```

Comment: Thank you very much Francisco!

It works like a dream now!

Pieter Steenekamp

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to accept the stackoverflow answers as correct when they solve the question you are answering http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer